# Can't play older game on Windows Surface Pro

Tags: technical-issues, star-wars-kotor

I've been trying to install both Anachronox, and Star Wars: KOTOR on my 128gb Windows Surface Pro.  I can install fine, but both crash on startup.  I've googled everything i possibly can - installed all updates, patches, driver updates, etc, that i can think of.  Anachronox crashes as soon as i click the icon with "Anox.exe ha stopped working" and kotor crashes after the space ship splash screen, with no error whatsoever.

I feel like this has something to do with the graphics (intel hd 4000 on the surface pro) but i cannot for the life of me make any progress.  Does anyone hve any recommendations on what to try?  Thankyou so much for any advice.

Comment: Compatibility mode is always my first guess? Are you using Steam? Have you checked can I run this to verify your hardware meets the standards?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with anachronox. The problem ended up being that my drivers were TOO up to date. Anachronox uses some feature of openGL that isn't supported by modern drivers. There are lots of ways to fix it but the simplest is to roll your drivers back... WAY back.